# How do you go from $E[X]$ equation to $Var(x)$ equation in the picture?

Tags: expected-value, variance

On the following picture, how do you go from equation 4 to 6? I just don't get how variance can be derived from expected value.

Thank you so much

[image: 1]

Comment: Where's the picture?

Comment: You really should type it out.

Comment: sorry guys first time using it

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide on how to format equations on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You should state that the random variables $\{D_{t}\}$ is i.i.d, and is independent to the random variable $L$, then we can get the following deduction:

\begin{align*}
Var(X) &=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=E\left[(\sum^{L}_{t=1}D_t)^2\right]-E[X]^2 \\
&=E\left[\sum^{L}_{t=1}D^2_t+\sum^{L}_{i=1}\sum^{L}_{j=1,j\neq i}D_iD_j\right]-l^2d^2 \\
&=E[L]E[D^2_t]+E(D_i)E[D_j]E[L(L-1)]-l^2d^2 \\
&=l(d^2+\sigma^2_D)+d^2(l^2-l+\sigma^2_L)-l^2d^2 \\
&=l\sigma^2_D+d^2\sigma^2_L.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}&\mathsf E(X) 
\\[2ex]=~&\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid L))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid L))&&\text{Law of Total Variance}
\\[2ex] =~&\mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(\sum_{t=1}^LD_t\mid L))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(\sum_{t=1}^L D_t\mid L))&&X=\sum_{t=1}^LD_t
\\[2ex] =~&\mathsf E(\sum_{t=1}^L\mathsf {Var}(D_t\mid L))+\mathsf{Var}(\sum_{t=1}^L\mathsf E( D_t\mid L))&&{\text{Linearity of Expectation,}\\\text{ Bilinearity of Covariance}\\\text{ and uncorrelation of all $D_t$}}
\\[2ex] =~&\mathsf E(\sum_{t=1}^L~\mathsf{Var}(D_t))+\mathsf{Var}(\sum_{t=1}^L~\mathsf E(D_t))&&\text{independence of $L$ and $D_t$}
\\[2ex]=~&\mathsf E(L~\mathsf{Var}(D_1))+\mathsf{Var}(L~\mathsf E(D_1))&&\text{identical distribution of all $D_t$}
\\[2ex]=~&\mathsf E(L)~\mathsf{Var}(D_1)+\mathsf{Var}(L)~\mathsf E(D_1)^2&&{\text{expectation, and variance,}\\\text{ of a scalar product of a RV}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have one more quick question. I get std dev = square root of variance but why does std dev of D square only gets ^2 erased? (From equation five to six)

Comment: That's clearly a typo, @HyonKim .  It should be: $$\sigma_{\small X} = \sqrt{~\ell\sigma_{\small D}^2+d^2\sigma_{\small L}^2~}$$

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your thorough comment. Can you elaborate a little bit on step 4~6. Thank you so much for help

Comment: 4: $D_t$ and $L$ are independent, so the condtional expectation and variance, are simply the expectation and variance.$$\mathsf E(D_t\mid L)=\mathsf E(D_t)\\\mathsf{Var}(D_t\mid L)=\mathsf{Var}(D_t)$$

Comment: 5: Each $D_t$ has identical distribution, so their expectations and variances are the same.$$\begin{align}\sum_{t=1}^L\mathsf E(D_t)&=\sum_{t=1}^L\mathsf E(D_1)\\&=L~\mathsf E(D_1)\end{align}$$

Comment: 6: the Expectation and Variance of $D_1$ will be scalar values (constants), and for any random variable $Z$ and constant $a$:$$\mathsf E(aZ)=a\mathsf E(Z)\\\mathsf{Var}(aZ)=a^2\mathsf{Var}(Z)$$

Comment: How about step 3? sorry I should've asked all at once. Thank you!

Comment: Expectation is a Linear operator, so the expectation of a sum is the sum of expectations.  $$\mathsf E(\sum_i Z_i)=\sum_i\mathsf E(Z_i)$$Covariance is Bilinear, so $$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(\sum_i Z_i)&=\mathsf{Cov}(\sum_i Z_i,\sum_j Z_j)\\&=\sum_i\sum_j\mathsf{Cov}(Z_i, Z_j) \end{align}$$Finally, the Covariance of independent variables (ie when $i\neq j$) equals zero.$$\sum_i\sum_j\mathsf{Cov}(Z_i, Z_j)=\sum_i\mathsf{Var}(Z_i)+\sum_i\sum_{j:j\neq i} 0$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a quick question about E[X] = E[L]E[Dt] part on the photo.
Can average value be solved by just multiplying those two average values (L and Dt) like that? Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: Yes, *when* the variables are *independent* (or at least *uncorrelated*).

Comment: Thank you so much!